# Java permanent switch

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I have class with 2 states which are defined by the value of an attribute (e.g. started that can be true of false)

When I call a method from an instance I want to get a different behaviour depending on the state.
I'm currently using an if statement that will query for the state every time the method is called but I think that there might be a quicker way to do this (something like polymorphism maybe?)

Is there an elegant way to implement this? I've thought of having two subclasses inherinting and casting them when the behave changes but maybe there's something better

A dummy example below (my actual problem is much more time consuming and hence the need for improvement)

```
public class StateChangingClass {
private boolean started;

public StateChangingClass() {
    started = false;
}

public void start(){started = true;}
public void end(){started = false;}

public boolean checkCondition(double time) {
    if (started) {
        if (time>0) {return true;}
        else {return false;}
        }

    else {return false;}
    }
```

}

Comment: your example code is far too simplistic, what is your actual problem, show the problem in code, maybe add comments what operation is expensive and where you want to something different.

Comment: "I think that there might be a quicker way to do this" I strongly doubt this is going to be slow. `return started && time > 0;` is pretty simple to evaluate.

Comment: I feel like if not the actual code, but still a proper simulation of actual code would have been better. This can be solved using ternary as well.

Comment: Study the design pattern. Factory Design pattern seems best for this case.

Comment: Imo definitely State design pattern, https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state

Comment: There is something called strategy pattern as well, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm which is similar to state design pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example it is way too much, but maybe you get an idea of how you can use it in your situation. I have added an interface 'ConditionChecker' which has two implementations. The Methods 'start' and 'end' just set the needed ConditionChecker.

```
public class StateChangingClass {

  private ConditionChecker conditionChecker;

  public StateChangingClass() {
    conditionChecker = StartedChecker.INSTANCE;
  }

  public void start() {
    conditionChecker = StartedChecker.INSTANCE;
  }

  public void end() {
    conditionChecker = EndChecker.INSTANCE;
  }

  public boolean checkCondition(double time) {
    return conditionChecker.check(time);
  }

  interface ConditionChecker {

    boolean check(double time);
  }

  static class StartedChecker implements ConditionChecker {

    public static final ConditionChecker INSTANCE = new StartedChecker();

    @Override
    public boolean check(double time) {
      return (time > 0);
    }
  }

  static class EndChecker implements ConditionChecker {

    public static final ConditionChecker INSTANCE = new EndChecker();

    @Override
    public boolean check(double time) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```